# Example of scala MultiMap where the entry types differ

Tags: scala, scala-collections, multimap

I'd like to have different types of entries for a single Long key.

So given I have a key of 1 I'd like to have the following entries:

1, "dog"
1, 3

First of all is it possible to contain entries of both String and Int types and if so, can I see an example of a HashMap with MultiMap mixed in showing how to add the entries and then access only the "dog" entry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want your map to contain a mixture of two types of entries, you can use an `Either`.  `Either` is like `Option` except that instead of having `Some` vs. `None` you have `Left` vs. `Right`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.Set
import scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap

val m = new HashMap[Int, Set[Either[Int, String]]] with MultiMap[Int, Either[Int, String]]

m.addBinding(1, Right("dog"))
m.addBinding(1, Left(3))

m(1).collect{ case Right(s) => s }             // Set(dog)
m.mapValues(_.collect{ case Right(s) => s })   // Map(1 -> Set(dog))
```